# using array and variable from django in html

Tags: python, html, arrays, django

please advice me how i can using the array and variable in one command? 
because in the django i have error :

> "Could not parse the remainder: '[show]' from 'host_value[show]'"

there is my code:

```
<form action="" method="post" >{% csrf_token %}
{% for show in showing %}
        <p><input id="autocomplete{{show}}" size="35" value="{{host_value[show]}}" name="hosts{{show}}"  title="type &quot;hostname&quot;"></p>
{% endfor %}
</form>
```

my problem in the value of input, i try to set value from array host_value with index "show"

how i can do this?

Comment: Are you using an array or a dictionary ???

Comment: no array, for example my host_value is : [u'zabbix2', u'Zabbix server']

Comment: so what is 'show' then because that looked like an index?

Comment: show this a variable, who show number from 0 to my setting showing number

Answer (score 0):

Django template syntax for a dictionary:

```
{{ host_value.show }}
```

- use a dot
- you want spaces after **{{** and before **}}** by convention

For an array:

```
{{ host_value.0 }}
```

Comment: yeah thanks, when i try host_value.0 them is working, but when host_value.show, no...

Comment: can i use in array not zero but some variable?

Comment: What do you mean use some variable?